# Are the two JavaScript functions working identically?

Tags: javascript

Here is the function `require`

```
  function require(url, cb = new Function) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = url;
    s.async = true;
    s.onload = cb;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }
```

Here is `require2`:

```
  function require2(url, cb = new Function) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = url;
    s.onload = cb;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }
```

The only difference is the first function has a async assignment. I am wondering, is it possible to just remove that?

Thanks,

Comment: No. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0):

Here is more info: [HTML  async Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp)

it specifies that the script will be executed asynchronously as soon as it is available.

if you do not need it, you can remove